# Firmly connect bricks in a triangle

Tags: building, snot, angles

I need to connect two bricks onto a plate such that the plate is facing up, and the two bricks are facing out from above it at an angle (say 30 degrees) but are connected firmly, at opposite ends with their studs facing out.

Ideally this would fit in around a 2 x 4 brick size, and not be too fragile.

[image]

The top image shows the two plates (assume 2x2) facing out at an angle from the 4 by 4 plate below.

The bottom image is the same from above.
What I'd like to figure out is what to put in between. Assume that there will be stuff attached to the 2x2 plates, enough that the standard 2x1 hinge will probably just flop.

Comment: A drawing would be nice

Comment: Can the two angled pieces be connected to one another? That would strengthen the overall structure.

Comment: The triangle is Isoceles, but not equilateral. The two angled pieces are not at 90 degrees to each other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How firm does it need to be? Wouldn't something like this be enough?

[image: Slopes!]

If not, you can try to lock the parts into place with "cheese" slopes, but it's not as neat:

[image: Slopes! And cheese!]

Comment: That should work. I'll have to dig around to find the 2x2 tops for the hinge, I definitely have cheese slopes  - if I can find grey or dark blue ones - I think the bottom assembly would be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but could you use hinges?

Like these?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps click hinges - but normal hinges are too floppy. I am going to put together a drawing later (no scanner handy) to explain better what I want to achieve. That looks like an old hinge - the middle finger is missing.

Comment: @DannyStaple: It shouldn't be floppy once it's built, since it forms an equilateral triangle it _should_  hold well.

Comment: Not sure you can make a 60° angle with these, though. Seems too acute.